# Changing ffmpeg showwaves to white

Tags: ffmpeg, colors, waveform

I've looked over all the entries on showwaves and I'm 99% to where I want to be, but I cannot figure out how to get my waveform to show as white. No matter what I change, I'm still getting black waveforms. I'm hoping for a slightly transparent white waveform over the image background.

```
ffmpeg -i 00002.wav -i MarsSurface.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=cline:colors=white|white|white:rate=24:scale=lin,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.001,format=yuva420p[v];[1:v]scale=1920:1080[bg];[bg][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

Any ideas what I'm missing? I'm guessing it's something small here, but I'm missing it.

Comment: Hello, what's that black `colorkey` filter for?

Comment: It removes the black background from the showwaves video

Comment: Unfortunately no. the opacity brings everything down. Without the colorkey it's just all black, coloring one channel doesn't work either.

Comment: Please answer all the questions that are asked - you missed the ffmpeg version one. As for background opacity, I confused a filter for a second, `showwaves` doesn't have mentioned option. But by default I see no background in the 1st place + my wave is white as it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is intended to display an audio inputs sample waves as a video output, with transparency applied to the output sample waves, and then overlaid onto a background image.
The comments relate to the original question.

The following generates a white sample wave output on a black background.

> `scale=lin` (linear) is not required as this is the default. `colors` sets
> the colour of each drawn channel. This only needs to be stated once if
> all channels are the same colour.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -filter_complex [0]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=cline:colors=white output.mp4
```

The following overlays the sample wave onto the background image.

> The black background colour from the above output will only be applied
> if no alternative background is made available before outputting.
> Therefore, no `colorkey` filter is required.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -i image.jpg -filter_complex [0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=cline:colors=white[v];[1]scale=1920:1080[bg];[bg][v]overlay[out] -map [out] -map 0:a output.mp4
```

Finally, before overlaying the sample wave to the background image, we can apply transparency to the sample waves `(0.5)` using the `format` filter. A value between `1` (fully opaque), and `0`(fully transparent), can be set.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -i image.jpg -filter_complex [0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=cline:split_channels=1:colors=white[v];[v]format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[vt];[1]scale=1920:1080[bg];[bg][vt]overlay[out] -map [out] -map 0:a output.mp4
```

In the above final example I’ve added the `split_channels=1` option, to separate the two channels for greater clarity (optional).

All the above is only intended to answer the original question (which would benefit from some editing). The ffmpeg documentation offers further useful additional settings under the **Multimedia filters** section: **18.29 showwaves**.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves

Comment: I'm so confused by this question, comments and how this answer is the solution. This command only additionally sets opacity on the white waves, it has nothing to do with any sort of black background as in the comments, neither does it anything different to colorize the waves.

Comment: The OP was mistakingly using the black background to generate transparency. The requirement was for the white waves,  with some transparency, to overlay the background image, not a black background. But yes,  it was a slightly confusing question.

Comment: Have edited my answer in an attempt at  clarifying some of the original questions confusion.